# Cartesian equations for the line tangent to two surface.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I am asked to find a Cartesian equation for the line tangent to both the surfaces

x^2+y^2+2z^2=4  and z=e^(x-y) at the point (1.1.1)

I tried to find out normal vector to both surfaces and tangent plane at the point (1.1.1)

and it does not help me at all;;

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tangent planes to both curves at (1,1,1), then take the cross product of the two normal vectors to get the direction vector of the tangent line, since this will give you a vector that lies on both tangent planes.

Comment: I don't get your asnwer

Comment: The line tangent to both surfaces will lie on both tangent planes. Thus, you can first find the normal vectors to the tangent planes. The cross product will give you a vector that is perpendicular to those normal vectors, i.e. one that lies on both planes.